# Weak closure in Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I am trying to find weak closure of $\{e^{imt}+me^{int}|0\le m<n\}$ in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$.

I know how to find weak sequential closure and I know that $0$ is in weak closure (I can prove it using weak open sets). Now, how to find or even guess what is weak closure and then prove that really is weak closure?

I am aware that weak sequential closure and weak closure are not the same.
Is the only way using weakly open sets (which are not so nice) or is there some trick to quickly deduce what is weak closure?

Also, I know that in a locally convex space weak closure and original closure of a convex set are the same. Here, we do not have a convex set....
Please help, I do not know how to begin this.

Comment: It would help if we knew *which* Hilbert space you are talking about.

Comment: I mean $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. Sorry.

Comment: In that case your answer is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653151/find-the-weak-sequential-closure-of-a-set-in-l2-pi-pi?rq=1).

Comment: @TooOldForMath, thank you for the link, I see it is the same set. But I need weak closure. There they found weak sequential closure. They are not the same, right?

Comment: This question asks about the weak closure. The so-called "duplicate" concerns the weak *sequential* closure. (The OP even states he knows how to find the weak sequential closure.)